# Getting error installing prisma using bunjs

Tags: prisma, bun

```
error: postinstall script from "@prisma/engines" exited with 2
```

This is the error I am getting when I run command "bunx prisma init" is "error: `postinstall` script from "@prisma/engines" exited with 2". Nothing I am getting on how to resolve this.